# Syncing Google Tasks w/ iCal

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, google-calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you syncronize Google Calendar and iCal?](https://superuser.com/questions/832/how-do-you-syncronize-google-calendar-and-ical)

Is there a way to sync Google Tasks to iCal on OSX? Google Tasks appears in my Google Calendar, however the XML/iCal is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

impossible. as of now.